# InDesign export to px size and high res

Tags: adobe-indesign, png, resolution, image-quality, jpg

I have seen you advise on exporting to a pixel size from InDesign by using the 72ppi to get the actual pixel size; however I also end up getting a poor quality resolution.

How can I both get the pixel size and a better ppi?

I am exporting to jpg or png (web banner)

thanks :)

Comment: What are you exporting for?

Comment: I am exporting to jpg or png (web banner).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, be advised InDesign is primarily a print-oriented tool or in any case a PDF-generating tool. It is not wrong, but uncommon, to create web assets in JPG/PNG via InDesign. Unless there is a specific reason to use InDesign (eg. for its automation features), its more common to design web banners in PS or AI.

This aside, exporting at 72ppi is 'normal' for web assets, unless you are designing for retina displays which might use a higher ppi count. Make sure you don't use any compression when saving your JPG or PNG.

You could increase (2x) the ppi or pixel size and then update the CSS code to scale down the banner to 50% if that's an option. This could result in a better render quality of your artwork, but a larger banner file size.

Answer (score 0):

### 72 ppi is a curse from the evil ancient spirits of archaic computers! 72 ppi begone!

### Normal computers are *closer* to 96ppi

Yes. Let me do some math for you.

For example a 14" laptop screen will have:

- Arround 12.2 inches at the base.
- If it has a resolution of 1366pxx768 the operation is:
  1366px/12.2i = 112ppi.

But at 1280x720 will be

1280/12.2=105

Another example, a 23" monitor will have:

- 20" at base
- 1920/20=96

---

**1.** Make a decision on what is the final pixel size you really need. Pixel in px units... forget the inches " physical units. Xo)

**2.** Play with the settings on whatever you have on your InDesign file to export at that final pixel size.

**3.** Although 72ppi has no sense, still, the applications use it, so probably 72ppi will export the asset at the dimension you intended to. Do what Lucian proposed in his answer. Export at 2x.